# xampp with limited user in windows

Tags: windows, xampp, limited-user-account

I have installed xampp-1.7.4 for my windows xp machine.

I could not use it with limited user account.

I want to use xampp with limited user in windows xp. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed xampp as service and it working for all users fine.